# How to copy a list files to a list of directories or subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, find, cp, xargs

I'm trying to figure out how to copy a list of files to a list of subdirectories.

eg. I have 300 files to copy into 300 subdirectories - 1 to 1.

```
file1  ->  dir1/sub
file2  ->  dir2/sub
file3  ->  dir3/sub
file4  ->  dir4/sub
.
.
file300  ->  dir/sub300
```

I normally have the files in the current directory where the directories are located so i would run something like

```
find . -type f -name "file*"
```

copy to

```
find . -type d -name "dir*/sub"
```

What would be the best way to run such a script? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file1  ->  dir1/sub
file2  ->  dir2/sub
file3  ->  dir3/sub
file4  ->  dir4/sub
.
.
```

The names of files and directories are with numbers as above?

```
for i in {1..300}; do cp file$i dir$i/sub; done
```

Comment: To make people feel better about the variable expansion, use `file${i} dir${i}/sub`. Oh, omitting the curly braces will work fine. But the curly braces are a good habit if you're going to be adding things on the end of variables, whether or not the addition includes delimiters like slashes.

Comment: In general I agree.